How to write init function for a view with `@Binding`?
I have the following code and it works:
struct DetailView: View {
  var counter: Binding<Int>
  init(counter: Binding<Int>) {
    self.counter = counter
  }
  var body: some View {
    Text("counter: \(counter)")
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var counter = 1
  
  var body: some View {
    DetailView(counter: $counter)
  }
}

Then I change the binding to use @Binding, and the init function doesn't compile.
struct DetailView: View {
  @Binding var counter: Int
  init(counter: Binding<Int>) {
    self.counter = counter
  }
  var body: some View {
    Text("counter: \(counter)")
  }
}

This fails with error:

Cannot assign value of type 'Binding' to type 'Int'

However, when I remove the init function, it works again:
struct DetailView: View {
  @Binding var counter: Int
  var body: some View {
    Text("counter: \(counter)")
  }
}

I am wondering how can I write a custom init function for it?

It's best to avoid implementing an init because it needs to be as fast as possible since it can be called over and over again (body is only called if the init params change from last time)

This is how you assign Binding via the constructor.
However, I think it's not necessary. Obviously, DetailView(counter: $counter) is the correct way to go so far, unless you need to do something on the initial function. Notice: init could be called multiple times when @State var counter changes.
@State private var counter = 1 //State should be private

...
struct DetailView: View {
  @Binding var counter: Int
  init(counter: Binding<Int>) {
    self._counter = counter //<- Here
  }
}


ah, thanks! should i use @Binding over Binding?

@Binding is a property wrapper, it will automatically infer the type, in this case, is Int. Binding is a kind of type annotation. They're for different purposes. You can't access Binding directly without .wrappedValue.
